# how to user options in materialize css materialbox

Tags: css, image, zooming

I am trying to call the callback on zoom in and zoom out images but the function is not called, please help

```
$('.materialboxed').materialbox({
            onOpenStart: function(){
                imgZoomIn()
            },
            onOpenEnd: function(){
                imgZoomOut()
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please provide more code in your example. The issue might not be within that snipped you provided.

Comment: Please refer this site https://materializecss.com/media.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```js
$('.materialboxed').materialbox();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<img class="materialboxed" width="650" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Universal-Placeholder-Text-Lorem-Ipsum-Generator-getlorem.jpg">
```

Run the code snipped to check.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response I want the callback function when it gets zoom in and zooms out

Answer (score 0):

The following wasn't working for me, so I had to update my materialize references to this, actually I just added with the local materizalize.min files link I had:

```
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

And then, only initialize like this (for jquery):

```
$('.materialboxed').materialbox({
    inDuration:275,
    outDuration:200,
    onOpenStart: function() {console.log("onOpenStart");},
    onOpenEnd: function() {console.log("onOpenEnd");},
    onCloseStart: function() {console.log("onCloseStart");},
    onCloseEnd: function() {console.log("onCloseEnd");}
});
```